# parse onclick links in html

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I certain html page contains links that are displayed with each onclick event. I am unable to parse the html for the url that will follow these onlick links. If this is the source on the page, how do I capture the content that each onclick link displays. In other words for example:

```
<a href="#" onClick="SelGenre('001'); return false;">プライベート</a>&nbsp;(4236)</li>
```

なかま (1145)

ペット (398)

Now this is the onclick  link that will display some content which I need to capture. Basically I want to be able to activate the onclick event from a program to display and capture the url links from that specific page.
Hope this makes sense.i looked for javascript file but could not find it and firebug does not help much

Comment: I've tried really hard but I still can't work out what you're trying to do. Language isn't clear. What do you mean by capture? When the link is clicked what do you want to happen?

Comment: sorry if i was not clear. When the link is clicked on the actual website page a set of urls are displayed that is not in the initial source page. This seems to be some sort of script running that is activated when the link is clicked. Here take a look at this site and click on the links on the left.http://www.fruitblog.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to trace the script function properly and got the format of the url it uses when onclick is true.